# how to sum cell values by name in data grid view?

Tags: vb.net

hello i have created a form where i placed datagridview and two textboxes with name cash and card. i want to sum cash and card values separately and insert into sql database whenever i enter value in datagridview. my code is not working

```
Dim rw As New DataGridViewRow

For Each rw In DataGridView2.Rows
    For index As Integer = 0 To DataGridView2.RowCount - 1
        Dim u As string = rw.Cells(0).Value
        Dim v As string = rw.Cells(0).Value
        If rw.Cells(0).Value = "CASH" Then
            u += Convert.ToDouble(DataGridView2.Rows(index).Cells(1).Value)
            Label45.Text = u
        End If

        If rw.Cells(0).Value = "CARD" Then
            v += Convert.ToDouble(DataGridView2.Rows(index).Cells(1).Value)
            Label46.Text = u
        End If
    Next
Next
```

Comment: First you loop two times on the rows. Just the first foreach is enough. Second you add to the v variable but then update the label with the value of the u variable. These are just typos that you could easily spot yourself [talking to your rubberduck](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rubber_duck_debugging)

Comment: Some other advices, when you have code that doesn't work, it is a good thing adding any kind of error you receive. Also, you have two variables named u and v of type string. You expect them to be strings (from the cells(0)) or do you expect them to be numbers (from the cells(1))? VB.NET has a settings in its project configuration that will make these line of code errors if you use the _Option Strict On_ A variable should not be a string but also a number

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Comments and explanations in-line

```
Private Sub OPCode2()
    'Give names to variables that are meaningful
    Dim TotalCash As Double
    Dim TotalCard As Double
    'just one loop
    For Each rw As DataGridViewRow In DataGridView2.Rows
        'resolve values of cells just once for each iteration
        Dim MethodOfPayment As String = rw.Cells(0).Value.ToString
        Dim value As Double = CDbl(rw.Cells(1).Value)
        'Single If statement with an ElseIf
        If MethodOfPayment = "CASH" Then
            TotalCash += value
            'Don't updat the label on every iteration - slows things down
            'Label45.Text = u
        ElseIf MethodOfPayment = "Card" Then
            TotalCard += value
        End If
    Next
    'Update labels only once after the loop
    Label45.Text = TotalCash.ToString
    Label46.Text = TotalCard.ToString
End Sub
```

Comment: Please always trim values when working with data in order to get the desired output.

Comment: @preciousbetine, not always, only if I expects input data to be with trailed spaces ;)

Answer (score 0):

Here is an alternative to consider if you understand working with lambda, otherwise Mary's will work for you.

Make sure to read all the comments before trying out the code below so you have some understanding rather than simply trying the code so you can learn from what's being presented.

Written in Visual Studio 2017

```
Imports System.Data.SqlClient
''' <summary>
''' Assumes cell 1 data is numeric
''' One DataGridView, two columns
''' 0 - PaymentTypeColumn
''' 1 - AmountColumn
''' Two TextBox controls
''' One Button
''' </summary>
Public Class Form1
    Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
        DataGridView2.Rows.Add("CASH", 200.5)
        DataGridView2.Rows.Add("CARD", 200.5)
        DataGridView2.Rows.Add("CASH", Nothing)
        DataGridView2.Rows.Add("CARD", 10.25)
        DataGridView2.Rows.Add("CASH", 25.0)
    End Sub
    ''' <summary>
    ''' Use Lambda to get values then sum them.
    ''' </summary>
    ''' <param name="sender"></param>
    ''' <param name="e"></param>
    Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click

        Dim cash = DataGridView2.
                Rows.
                Cast(Of DataGridViewRow).
                Where(Function(row) CStr(row.Cells("PaymentTypeColumn").Value) = "CASH").
                Select(Function(row) CDbl(row.Cells("AmountColumn").Value)).
                Sum()


        Dim card = DataGridView2.
                Rows.
                Cast(Of DataGridViewRow).
                Where(Function(row) CStr(row.Cells("PaymentTypeColumn").Value) = "CARD").
                Select(Function(row) CDbl(row.Cells("AmountColumn").Value)).
                Sum()


        cashTextBox.Text = cash.ToString("c2")
        cardTextBox.Text = card.ToString("c2")

        '
        ' Get AddNewRecord method ready to use before un-commenting code
        '
        'Dim ops As New DataOperations
        'Dim id = ops.AddNewRecord(cash, card)

    End Sub
    ''' <summary>
    ''' Alternate if unsure all cells values in AmountColumn column are numeric,
    ''' do a TryParse.
    ''' </summary>
    ''' <param name="sender"></param>
    ''' <param name="e"></param>
    Private Sub Button2_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button2.Click
        Dim cash = DataGridView2.
                Rows.
                Cast(Of DataGridViewRow).
                Where(Function(row) CStr(row.Cells("PaymentTypeColumn").Value) = "CASH").
                Select(Function(row)
                           Dim value As Double = 0
                           Double.TryParse(CStr(row.Cells("AmountColumn").Value), value)
                           Return value
                       End Function).
                Sum()
        cashTextBox.Text = cash.ToString("c2")
    End Sub
End Class
''' <summary>
''' Keep here or place in in a separate class file
''' </summary>
Public Class DataOperations
    Private ConnectionString As String = "TODO"
    ''' <summary>
    ''' Returns new primary key (optional), you have a primary key though.
    ''' </summary>
    ''' <param name="cash">cash amount</param>
    ''' <param name="card">card amount</param>
    ''' <returns>new primary key</returns>
    ''' <remarks>
    '''  - highly advisable to wrap the open operation and
    '''    Execute method in a try/catch and deal with any runtime errors
    '''    back in the UI
    ''' </remarks>
    Public Function AddNewRecord(cash As Double, card As Double) As Integer
        Dim newPrimaryKey As Integer = 0

        Dim insertStatement As String = "INSERT INTO SomeTable (Cash,Card) VALUES (@Cash,@Card);" &
                                        "SELECT CAST(scope_identity() AS int);"

        Using cn = New SqlConnection() With {.ConnectionString = ConnectionString}
            Using cmd = New SqlCommand() With {.Connection = cn, .CommandText = insertStatement}
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Cash", cash)
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Card", card)
                cn.Open()
                newPrimaryKey = Convert.ToInt32(cmd.ExecuteScalar())
            End Using
        End Using
        Return newPrimaryKey
    End Function
End Class
```

Comment: It seems that the rows will be iterated twice with the lambda method. Is this so?

Comment: Yes but unless we are talking about a very large row count there will be no noticable difference in execution time.